# form creation works but not submit

Tags: jquery, forms

```
 var str = $('<form>').attr({
     action: data.action,
     method: 'POST',
     name: 'form'
 });

 $.each(data.form , function( index, value ) {
     str.append($('<input>').attr({
             type: value.type,
             name: value.name,
             alue: value.value
         })
     );
 });

 str.appendTo('body');
 str.submit();
```

`data.form` is a array and it includes form files. This is the code I used to create a dynamic form and to submit it. form creation is successful but the submit part is not working. why ?

Comment: can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: what is this,it may be value:value.value   str.append($('<input>').attr({
             type: value.type,
             name: value.name,
             alue: value.value 
         })
     );

Comment: creating a input element

Comment: is it alue: value.value OR value:value.value ?? @KalhanoToressPamuditha

Comment: sorry it should be value :)

Answer (score 0):

put your action inside Quotation.

```
 action: 'data.action',
 $.each('data.form' , function( index, value ) {});
```

[is this code right?](http://jsfiddle.net/JWfdx/12/)

Comment: could you check your console? output.

Comment: yeah checked all are fine except the submit part :(